# Can a delegate created for a base class method actually call a derived class method?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test.StartTest();
            ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class Test
    {
        class SomeResult {}

        class BaseClass
        {
            public virtual TResult DoSomething<TResult>()
            {
                WriteLine(nameof(BaseClass));
                return default;
            }
        }

        class DerivedClass : BaseClass
        {
            public override TResult DoSomething<TResult>()
            {
                WriteLine(nameof(DerivedClass));
                Func<TResult> baseImplementation = base.DoSomething<TResult>;
                //This works: return base.DoSomething<TResult>();
                return baseImplementation();
            }
        }


        public static void StartTest()
        {
            DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();
            instance.DoSomething<SomeResult>();
            //This works: instance.DoSomething<int>();
        
            WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I have `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` (which derives from `BaseClass`) inside the class `Test` (I don't think it's important that the former classes are inside `Test`, but I'll leave it like that in case I'm missing something).

`BaseClass` has the virtual method `DoSomething`, which `DerivedClass` overrides to call the base class implementation, but doing so by creating a `Func` delegate "pointing" to `BaseClass.DoSomething`, and calling that delegate (take into account this is just a barebones example and not exactly what I was trying to accomplish in a real project).

When running the program an instance of `DerivedClass` is created, and its `DoSomething` method is called, which should call `BaseClass.DoSomething` via the delegate as mentioned before. When I run it in Visual Studio it works as I would expect it to, `BaseClass.DoSomething` is indeed called (the output is "DerivedClass BaseClass Finished"). However, when running it elsewhere (the Unity game engine, but it's not relevant) the delegate does not call `BaseClass.DoSomething`, but `DerivedClass.DoSomething` (entering a loop and causing a stack overflow exception). It doesn't happen with the lines commented out with "//This works:", even though I'd assume them to be mostly equivalent.

**Wouldn't the expected behaviour be that calling the delegate always executes `BaseClass.DoSomething`, or am I missing something and it's an implementation detail and not a well-defined rule in the language?** My first assumption is that it's a bug in either Unity or the version of Mono that it uses, but I'm not sure if there's something else I have to consider.

Comment: Using Mono C# compiler 6.12, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @Sweeper I guess you mean the "unexpected" behaviour? I think the version of Unity I'm using uses Mono 5.11, though a previous Unity version in which I can't reproduce the issue also seems to use Mono 5.11.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour must be that the delegate executes the base class method, not the derived class method. I received confirmation from Unity that the backwards behaviour is indeed a bug.